# Javascript overriding/adding methods to the prototype

Tags: javascript

Basically, I want to know how/what's the difference between overriding/adding methods on instances of objects vs  methods on the 'Class' instance of JS objects (yes class isn't the right word, not sure what is though).

For example, why doesn't this work?

```
Date.prototype.now= function (){
    return 23;
}

$('#foo').append(Date.now());
```

And yet, this does?

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(){
    return 23;
}
var bar = Array();
bar[0] = "a";
$('#bar').append(bar.indexOf("a"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tad604/fMWKA/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`now` is a static method on `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now). It is not an instance method; not defined on `Date.prototype` to begin with. It is defined directly on the `Date` object. When you write

```
Date.prototype.now = function () {
    return 23;
}
```

you are not actually overwriting the function called by `Date.now()`.

---

On the other hand, [`indexOf` for arrays is an instance method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) That is, it's defined on `Array.prototype`, so when you write

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(){
    return 23;
};
```

you are in fact changing the `indexOf` function called by

```
var bar = [];
bar.indexOf('a');
```

---

See the difference? http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/7qVQy/

---

I recommend reading about the [JavaScript prototype lookup chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_constructor_prototype), which should clarify some of your confusion.

Comment: Thanks... I've got a mostly java/.net background and I suspected it was something along those lines, but didn't really know the right way to phrase the question/search with regards to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the static Date object and not it's constructor. from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date),

> Invoking JavaScript Date in a non-constructor context (i.e., without
>   the new operator) will return a string representing the current time.

Try this instead http://jsfiddle.net/fMWKA/4/

Comment: Not quite... `Date.now()` is simply a static method.

Answer (score 0):

true what MДΓΓ БДLL said. 
Just for educational purposes, you could create a new instance of Date and therefore use the method declared in the prototype.

```
Date.prototype.now = function() {
  return 23;
}
Date = new Date();
document.write(Date.now());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n9h4y/